# How to set a folder as classpath in jarbundler

Tags: macos, jarbundler

Hi using jar bundler of Mac 10.5.7. I can set any file as classpath. I have a folder which contains some database files. In my java program I am using this path. So how to set my folder in "class path and file section" in jarbundler.

http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Packaging/Packaging.html

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: I was able to add a folder in the "Additions to Classpath" section.  Is that what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question belong to serverfault. If I am not wrong then your problem is to give a single application to the end user which will run simply by double clicking on it. But the problem is that ur application refers to some path. so better compress those database file embed those things in your jar and then write the logic to extract the file and store the data in the path that you actually want. I would be preferred if u do the same for home directory means the data must be saved in home directory.

The above (extraction of zip file) should run for once only.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks Deepak, your response really helped me alot. I achieved my result